# Replace substring in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, replace

I have a string in the form `-content-`, and I would like to replace it with `&content&`. How can I do this with replace in PowerShell?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The built-in `-replace` operator allows you to use a regex for this e.g.:

```
C:\PS> '-content-' -replace '-([^-]+)-', '&$1&'
&content&
```

Note the use of single quotes is essential on the replacement string so PowerShell doesn't interpret the $1 capture group.

Comment: If you DO need your expressions inside double quotes, like when combining with $variables,  you can escape the capture group dollar signs ($) by preceding them with a backtick (`)

Answer (score 22):

PowerShell strings are just .NET strings, so you can:

```
PS> $x = '-foo-'
PS> $x.Replace('-', '&')
&foo&
```

...or:

```
PS> $x = '-foo-'
PS> $x.Replace('-foo-', '&bar&')
&bar&
```

Obviously, if you want to keep the result, assign it to another variable:

```
PS> $y = $x.Replace($search, $replace)
```

Comment: But this solution also match for -content and replace it to &content.