# Use Powershell to replace subsection of regex result

Tags: regex, string, powershell, replace

Using Powershell, I know how to search a file for a complicated string using a regex, and replace that with some fixed value, as in the following snippet:

```
Get-ChildItem  "*.txt" |
Foreach-Object {
    $c = ($_ | Get-Content)
    $c = $c -replace $regexA,'NewText'
    [IO.File]::WriteAllText($_.FullName, ($c -join "`r`n"))
}
```

Now I'm trying to figure out how to replace a *subsection* of each match of a regex. Can this be done in one smooth step like above? Or do you have to extract each match of the larger regex, search and replace within it, and then somehow stick that result back into the original text?

To clarify with an example, suppose that in the following test text I want to find only the 14xx-numbered instances like "TEST=*1404" in the following text, and replace the 14xx with 16xx?

```
A 2180 1830 12 0 3 3 TEST=C1404
A 900 1830 12 0 3 3 TEST=R1413
A 400 1830 12 0 3 3 TEST=R1411
A 1090 1970 12 0 3 3 TEST=U1400
A 1090 1970 12 0 3 3 TEST=CSA1400
A 1090 1970 12 0 3 3 TEST=CSA1414
A 1090 1970 12 0 3 3 TEST=CSA140
A 1090 1970 12 0 3 3 TEST=CSA14001
A 1090 1970 12 0 3 3 TEST=CSA17001
```

I.e. I'd like the resulting text to be as follows, where you'll note that only the first 6 lines should change:

```
A 2180 1830 12 0 3 3 TEST=C1604
A 900 1830 12 0 3 3 TEST=R1613
A 400 1830 12 0 3 3 TEST=R1611
A 1090 1970 12 0 3 3 TEST=U1600
A 1090 1970 12 0 3 3 TEST=CSA1600
A 1090 1970 12 0 3 3 TEST=CSA1614 <- Second instance of '14' shouldn't change
A 1090 1970 12 0 3 3 TEST=CSA140 <- Shorter numbers shouldn't change
A 1090 1970 12 0 3 3 TEST=CSA14001 <- Longer numbers shouldn't change
A 1090 1970 12 0 3 3 TEST=CSA17001
```

The following regex seems to do the job of finding the larger strings where I need to make replacements, but I don't know what functionality in Powershell (`replace`?) to use to just replace the substring of the results. Also, feel free to suggest a better regex if that would help.

```
$regexA = "\bTEST=\b[A-Za-z]+14\d\d\r"
```

I'd rather not have to hard-code an exhaustive list of the stuff that can come between the '=' and the numbers, like 'R', 'C', "CSA", etc.

I've been working on something for an hour or so where I get all the matches for the regex, search within them to replace 14 with 16, then run replace on the original text with the old and new values, e.g. `replace($myText,"TEST=CSA1400","TEST=CSA1600")`, but this is not covering off the special cases very well, and it feels like I'm heading down the rabbit-hole.

Comment: **Related post** - [Replace substring in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14912948/465053) **,** [Partial String Replacement using PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46056179/465053) **&** [Replacing Part of String at Position in Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39107733/465053)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You need to group the sub-expressions you want to preserve (i.e. put them between parentheses) and then reference the groups via the variables `$1` and `$2` in the replacement string. Try something like this:

```
$regexA = '( TEST=[A-Za-z]+)14(\d\d)$'

Get-ChildItem '*.txt' | ForEach-Object {
    $c = (Get-Content $_.FullName) -replace $regexA, '${1}16$2' -join "`r`n"
    [IO.File]::WriteAllText($_.FullName, $c)
}
```

Comment: +1 I was scratching my head over escaping that replacement agument.

Comment: In your method, is there any danger to adding a `-raw` to the `Get-Content` and removing the `join` from the replacement part?

Comment: @SSilk That should work, too, but you need to replace the `$` in the regular expression with something like `(\r|$)`.

Comment: Another follow-up question: what if the value I'm sticking in the middle is itself another variable, external to the regex, rather than a fixed value. E.g. if the `16` in your sample code were some variable `$number`, what do I need to do to get it recognized as such? When I try that with your code, it literally prints the variable name with `$`. Thanks.

Comment: After posting my last comment, I found it works if I break the regex into separate parts concatenated with `+` signs, and have no quotes around the external variable, e.g. replacing `'${1}16$2` with `'${1}'+$number+'$2'` works for me. Is there anything wrong with that approach? Thanks.

Comment: @SSilk If you want to use regular variables in the replacement string you need to use double quotes instead of single quotes, and escape the variables referencing the groups from the regular expression: ``"`$1$number`$2"``.

Comment: `'${1}16$2'` is an example to see how a capture group followed by a number works.

Comment: I do not get it: ..referencing the groups from the regular expression: "`$1$number`$2". Why backticks for $number which is a normal var? Is $1$num considered as a unit?

Comment: Thank you @Ansgar Wiechers, your comment about the $1 and $2 was very useful for a problem I had. Just wanted to thank you, your support is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example using a scriptblock delegate (sometimes called an evaluator):

```
$regex = [regex]'( TEST=\D+)14(\d{2})\s*$'
$evaluator = { '{0}16{1}' -f $args[0].Groups[1..2] }
filter set-number { $regex.Replace($_, $evaluator) }

foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem  "*.txt")
 {
   ($file | get-content) | set-number | Set-Content $file.FullName
 }
```

It's arguably more complex than the -replace operator, but lets you use powershell operators to construct the replacement text, so you can do anything you can put in a script block.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Get-ChildItem  "*.txt" |
Foreach-Object {
  $c = $_ | Get-Content | Foreach {$_ -replace '(?<=TEST=\D+)14(?=\d{2}(\D+|$))','16'}
  $c | Out-File $_.FullName -Enc Ascii
}
```

Comment: `$f = $_.FullName; (Get-Content $f) -replace ... | Out-File $f ...` is probably a more elegant approach.