# Replacing Part of String at Position in Powershell

Tags: c#, string, powershell

Right now i'm trying to convert my `C#` Code to an `PowerShell` Script.

My actual function in `C#` looks like this:

```
private static string ReplaceStringPartAt(string mainstring, int position, string replacement)
{
    StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder(mainstring);
    strBuilder.Remove(position, replacement.Length);
    strBuilder.Insert(position, replacement);
    return strBuilder.ToString();
}
```

And my `PowerShell` function like this:

```
function ReplaceStringPartAt($mainstring, $position, $replacement)
{
    $strBuilder =  New-Object System.Text.StringBuilder;
    $strBuilder.AppendLine($mainstring)
    $strBuilder.Remove($position, $replacement.Length);
    $strBuilder.Insert($position, $replacement);
    return $strBuilder.ToString();
}
```

But i alway get an `[System.Text.StringBuilder]` as return value.

What do i miss to make the function work again?

Comment: **Related post** - [Replace substring in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14912948/465053) **&** [Use Powershell to replace subsection of regex result](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19917106/465053)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many of the methods of the [`StringBuilder` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) return the same `StringBuilder` instance so you can chain multiple calls together.  This is harmless in C#, but in PowerShell you need to explicitly capture these return values so they don't appear in your function output.  You can either pipe them to `Out-Null`...

```
$strBuilder.AppendLine($mainstring) | Out-Null
$strBuilder.Remove($position, $replacement.Length) | Out-Null;
$strBuilder.Insert($position, $replacement) | Out-Null;
```

...or cast them to `[Void]`...

```
[Void] $strBuilder.AppendLine($mainstring)
[Void] $strBuilder.Remove($position, $replacement.Length);
[Void] $strBuilder.Insert($position, $replacement);
```

...or chain all of the calls (including `.ToString()`) together...

```
return $strBuilder.AppendLine($mainstring) `
    .Remove($position, $replacement.Length) `
    .Insert($position, $replacement) `
    .ToString();
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast solutions!