# Partial String Replacement using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, replace

#### Problem

I am working on a script that has a user provide a specific IP address and I want to mask this IP in some fashion so that it isn't stored in the logs. My problem is, that I can easily do this when I know what the first three values of the IP typically are; however, I want to avoid storing/hard coding those values into the code to if at all possible. I also want to be able to replace the values even if the first three are unknown to me.

Examples:

```
10.11.12.50 would display as XX.XX.XX.50
10.12.11.23 would also display as XX.XX.XX.23
```

I have looked up partial string replacements, but none of the questions or problems that I found came close to doing this. I have tried doing things like:

```
# This ended up replacing all of the numbers
$tempString = $str -replace '[0-9]', 'X'
```

I know that I am partway there, but I aiming to only replace only the first 3 sets of digits so, basically every digit that is before a '.', but I haven't been able to achieve this.

#### Question

Is what I'm trying to do possible to achieve with PowerShell? Is there a best practice way of achieving this?

Comment: Use a regular expression replacement pattern

Comment: **Related post** - [Replace substring in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14912948/465053)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[TheIncorrigible1's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46056368/45375) is an exact way of solving the problem (replacement only happens if 3 consecutive `.`-separated groups of 1-3 digits are matched.)

A looser, but shorter solution that replaces everything but the last `.`-prefixed digit group:

```
PS> '10.11.12.50' -replace '.+(?=\.\d+$)', 'XX.XX.XX'
XX.XX.XX.50
```

`(?=\.\d+$)` is a (positive) [lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (`(?=...)`) that *matches* the enclosed subexpression (a literal `.` followed by 1 or more digits (`\d`) at the end of the string (`$`)), but doesn't *capture* it as part of the overall match.

The net effect is that only what `.+` captured - everything *before* the lookahead assertion's match - is replaced with `'XX.XX.XX'`.

Applied to the above example input string, `10.11.12.50`:

- `(?=\.\d+$)` matches the `.`-prefixed digit group at the end, `.50`.
- `.+` matches everything *before* `.50`, which is `10.11.12`.
- Since the `(?=...)` part isn't captured, it is therefore not included in what is *replaced*, so it is only substring `10.11.12` that is replaced, namely with `XX.XX.XX`, yielding `XX.XX.XX.50` as a result.

Comment: @Brandon: Correct; I've updated the answer again to explain it with a concrete example.

Answer (score 3):

Here's *an* example of how you can accomplish this:

```
Get-Content 'File.txt' |
  ForEach-Object { $_ = $_ -replace '\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}','xx.xx.xx' }
```

This example matches a digit 1-3 times, a literal period, and continues that pattern so it'll capture anything from `0-999.0-999.0-999` and replace with `xx.xx.xx`

Comment: PERFECT!! Thank you. That gave me the control I desired. I tried to choose this as the answer, but it told me that it was too soon to pick an answer

Comment: ++, but I assume you didn't mean to put the `$_ = ` there (assigning to `$_` should generally be avoided, and in this case it would also prevent output).

Comment: @mklement0 It's intentional and fine to do if you're going to re-use `$_` in the current scriptblock.  I don't know his use-case, but it looks like he just wants to obfuscate it in his console output, so my example is partially applicable in his exact use-case.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1: Understood, but note that [changes are coming](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3695#issuecomment-324491388) that will produce an editor warning when you assign to `$_` (making `$_` read-only in the _engine_ was ultimately rejected to avoid break existing code).

Comment: @mklement0 very interesting read.  Good decision overall, kind of bites for legacy code.